# AngularJs - Share data across multiple functions inside factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I am just starting to learn Angularjs so i might be using the whole thing wrong but please correct me.

I have the following factory that goes like this:

```
app.factory('MenuService',['service1','service2','service3',function(service1,service2,service3){

    var var1 = [],
        var2 = [],
        var3 = [];

    service1.getDataMethod(function(data){
        // processes data and saves it in var1
    });

    service2.getDataMethod2(function(data)){

    });

    /// same goes for service3.

    return {"prop2": var1, "prop2" : var2, "prop3": var3};
}])
```

I need to process the data return by service2 , based on data returned in the first service but every time i try to access it, the variable is empty.

I know the functions return a promise, is there a way to tell the second function to wait for the first one to finish in order to be able to use the data it brings?

I hope i made myself understood. Let me know if i should add something else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access previous promise results in a .then() chain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/how-do-i-access-previous-promise-results-in-a-then-chain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
service1.getDataMethod(function(data){
     // processes data and saves it in var1
}).then(function(data) {
  return service2.getDataMethod2(data)
})
```

Basically each promise have `.then()` method. So you can chain this as much as you need `a.then().then().then()`

In addition, some promise implementations have method wrappers such as `.success()` and `.error()`. These methods works similar to `.then()`

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your response. I tried it with .then(...) but i get the following console error: "service1.getDataMethod(...).then" is not a function

Comment: @IvanSt In this case make sure that `getDataMethod()` return promise

Comment: getDataMethod(function(data){....})  the data parameter contains the data returned by getDataMethod and its a resolved promise containing the data. After being processed it gets saved in var1, but when i try to access it from service2.getDataMethod2 to process it, the variable is empty.

Answer (score 0):

in angular you have access to $q service that is implementation of q library that works with promises. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q
If you don't like it for some reason try [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to chain your promises:

```
service1.getDataMethod(function(data){
    return something; // this is important, only that way you will be
                      // able to use the next .then()
})
.then(function(something) { // what you returned previously will be the function's argument

    return service2.getDataMethod2(data);
})
.then(function(result) { // `result` is what getDataMethod2 resolves

})
.catch(function(err) {
    // very important to add .catch to handle errors
});
```